# Separate strings from given string

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

NSString *str = @"Hello {{{separate this}}} and also this {{{ also separate this}}} world"

I need output in array:

**hello** : *at index 0 in array*

**separate this** : *at index 1 in array*

**and also this** : *at index 2 in array*

**also separate this** : *at index 3 in array*

**world** : *at index 4 in array*

Comment: Use `NSString` methods `[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:<#(NSString *)#> withString:<#(NSString *)#>]` and `[str componentsSeparatedByString:<#(NSString *)#>]` to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code will give you result as you specified in question.

**BEWARE !!!** - This code only works for static symbols combination mention in your question `{{{` and `}}}`. If any change made in that combination than you will not have desired result.

```
NSString *str = @"Hello {{{sepearte this}}} and also this {{{ also seperate this}}} world";

str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" {{{" withString:@"#"];
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"}}} " withString:@"#"];
NSArray *components = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str = @"Hello group1 group1 group1 and also this group2 group2 group2 world";
NSString *pattern = @"^Hello (.+) and also this (.+) world$";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                                                         error:nil];

NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:str
                                  options:0
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];
if ([matches count] == 2) {
    NSString *group1 = [str substringWithRange:[matches[0] range]];
    NSString *group2 = [str substringWithRange:[matches[1] range]];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Match failed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your string is wellformed, i.e. without any imbalanced braces, you can split on the braces:

```
NSArray<NSString *> *components = [[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"}}}" withString:@"{{{"] componentsSeparatedByString:@"{{{"];
```

And then eventually trim the resulting strings:

```
NSMutableArray<NSString *> *trimmedComponents = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *component in components) {
    [trimmedComponents addObject:[component stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]];
}
```